# How to determine if a related child-entity has been included

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a web application built with ASP.NET Core / EF Core with two entities "Products" and "ProductOptions" (one-to-many relationship).

When I execute a query to retrieve a Product from the database, is there a way to determine if the related ProductOptions (children of Product) have been included or not?
I need to distinguish between the following cases:

Case 1: a Product's related ProductOptions have been included in the query, but no ProductOptions have been found

```
public Product GetByIdIncludingProductOptions(int id)
{
    return DbContext.Products.Include(p => p.ProductOptions).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

Case 2: a Product's related ProductOptions haven't been included at all

```
public Product GetById(int id)
{
    return DbContext.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: @S.Akbari sorry, I forgot to specify that I'm using lazy loading. I'll edit my question to make it more precise. The question remains open.

Comment: There is **no** lazy loading in EF Core currently, hence the question is unclear.

Comment: @IvanStoev true, I added some code examples, hope it's more clear now

Comment: What about creating wrapper around entity with information about what was loaded during the query? as you know GetById is not including nothing and GetByIdIncludingProductOptions is including ProductOptions. Altering query with `.Select(p => new ProductWrapper { Entity = p, OptionsLoaded = true/false });`

Comment: @cloudikka that's impossible at this point of the development, since the shop is already in usage and this would mean a refactor of the complete application

Comment: Apparently there is a level of indirection in your code that obscures the origin of products. From what I read in your comments, also the ones under the answer, you better *always* get products with `ProductOptions` included. Probably easier than removing the indirection (although that would be better).

Comment: @GertArnold from my point of view, 1. it's pointless to retrieve ProductOptions in cases where they're not needed and 2. other/future developers may not be aware that they MUST include them to guarantee the correct functionality of the application. that's the reason why i wanted to do a manual check and throw the exception (to make them aware about this crucial point)

Comment: That seems pointless to me. Presumably, if a developer neglects to include it and it is in fact necessary, an exception will naturally be raised when an attempt is made to access it, which should then clue them in that they need to include it. Ultimately, this boils down to developers actually checking their work and/or having good automated testing to catch bugs like this. If those aren't in place, there's little you can ever do to prevent mistakes such as this, anyways.

Comment: @ChrisPratt while in case of a parent entity we could sort it out easily (if parent == null throw Exception), for a child it's not that easy, since it's technically possible to obtain an empty collection both because the parent doesn't have any children in the database or because the developer forgot to load them.
we must also consider that in such a big project it's almost impossible to make all developers conscious about all details of the various implementations. therefore, from my point of view it's not a matter of being negligent in this particular case

Comment: There's actually no ambiguity in the case of a collection. The collection will be null if not included and empty (but not null) if included, but there's no items. This is in itself enough for you to test against, if you want to determine if it's been included or not. Regardless, again, the answer is automated testing.

Comment: @ChrisPratt true; when we declared the Product-model, we set the initial value of the ProductOptions (child-class) to an empty List instead of leaving it to zero. considering the current problem, it probably hasn't been a good idea.

Comment: Well, no. In a sense, you *created* the problem. By auto-initializing the list, you added ambiguity, and now you're trying to figure out how to remove the ambiguity you added. If you want the developer to know instantly if they have neglected to include, then you should *not* default the property to an empty list. The only reason to add the default is if the fact that's it's not defined is not important (which is obviously not the case).

Comment: @ChrisPratt yes, now I agree with you. Finally I see the consequences of our former decision.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ChangeTracker to check if reference is loaded. You probably want to do something like:

```
var isLoaded = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<Products>()
    .FirstOrDefault(ee => ee.Entity == product)
    .Reference(e => e.ProductOptions)
    .IsLoaded;
```

Comment: yes, this is a big step in the right direction. so, assuming that i must do this check in my web-layer of my 3-tier application (and throw an exception in case the related child-entities haven't been included at all), how would it be possible to use this solution elegantly without having to include references to my db-layer into my web-layer?

Comment: Why you would like to throw an exception? it is some not expected state with lazy loading? You can just load the related references by calling Load() method. I suggest you to take a look at [ChangeTracking namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking) and it's objects. There is a lot of magic that can help you do the trick!

Comment: Because I have a method to determine the availability of a payment method depending on the ProductOptions of the Products of an Order. This method takes a List of Products as parameter and is used at various points of the application. To determine the availability correctly I must be 100% sure that the related ProductOptions have been included in the products-parameter. If they're not, I want to throw an exception like "hey developer, pay attention: when you execute this method, you must remember to include the ProductOptions to the  products-parameter".

Comment: @Dario since you have this `Repository` or whatever class encapsulating `DbContext`, just add a method onto it to check that. However, in general your abstraction is leaky - `GetById` should NOT return the same model as `GetByIdIncludingProductOptions` to make it explicit. Otherwise it is pointless.

Comment: @zaitsman sounds good. do you have a sample source-code? the ideal solution would be to make it generic, e.g. to check if child-entities X have been included for parent-entity Y

Comment: Also @cloudikka i imagine this solution would not work if they did `.AsNoTracking().Include()`

Comment: @zaitsman: That is true. It wont work without tracking enabled. In that case they should take care by themselves.